# Fibonacci & for loop: how are the commands executed step by step?

Tags: bash, fibonacci

```
#!/bin/bash
a=0
b=1
echo "give a number:"
read n
clear
echo "the fibonacci sequence until $n:"
for (( i=0; i<n; i++ ))
do
  echo -n "$a "
  c=$((a + b))
  a=$b
  b=$c
done
```

If I interpret it well, this code echoes a $a value after every i++ jumps, then switches the variables as you can see, then on the next i++ loop jump it happens again until "i" reaches "n".

Question: if we want in every loop jump the value of the new "c" why shall we echo $a? I see the connection that: a=$b, b=$c, and c=$((a + b)) but i don't get it why do we refer to $a when doing echo?

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Note The code is working well but i don't know why we echo $a instead of $c...

Comment: assuming you consider `0` and `1` as valid fibs ... at what point in the code would you display `0` and `1` if you only print `$c`? alternatively, update the question with what you expect the output should be and what the script actually generates

Comment: If you want to see it work, run `bash -x yourscript` to log each command as it's run. You can set `PS4=':$LINENO+'` to make those logs include the line number being executed. That should help you craft a narrow, more specific question -- right now, this is more a "why is the application logic designed as it is?", which is a question for the author; not "why does bash behave like it does?", which is a question category on-topic here.

Comment: If I may be snarky for a moment, "elegance" is not usually a top priority with shell scripts...

Comment: You print `$a` so you include 0 in the list.  You could just `echo -n 0` before the loop and echo `$c` inside the loop with the same effect.

Comment: You could also `echo "a=$a b=$b c=$c"` to just log complete state, which should make it obvious on observation

Comment: @TimRoberts if printing the entire fib series then `echo -n "$a $b "` before the loop, but then you also need to set `i` max to  `i<(n-2)` (assuming `0` and `1` are considered the first 2 entries in the fib series)

Comment: @markp-fuso No, you don't need to print `$b`.  That will get handled the first time you do `$a+$b`.  You are right that my suggestion would print one too many elements.

Comment: the fib series is `0 1 1 2 3 5 ...`, so `echo -n "$a $b "` otherwise you generate `0 1 2 3 5 ...`

Comment: Thank you for the answers you helped a lot. Some type of thought process was i searching for like Charles Duffy's answer. But i appreciate every answer. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You mean, *“never ever calculate anything needlessly, ever”*? It is *possible*, of course, but it depends on how much ugliness in the control logic you are willing to tolerate. In the example below, `fibonacci1` calculates at most one extra element of the series that may not get printed out and `fibonacci2` never calculates any extra series elements and everything makes it to the standard output.

Is any of that “elegant”? Probably not. This is actually a common problem most people encounter when coding (in languages other than purely functional ones): Most high(er)-level languages (unlike e.g. assemblers) provide predefined control structures that work great in typical and obvious cases (e.g. one control variable and one operation per iteration) but may become “suboptimal” in more complex scenarios.

A notoriously common example is a variable that stores a value from the previous iteration. Let’s assume you assign it at the very end of the loop. That works fine, but… Could you avoid the very last assignment (because it is useless), instead of leaving it to the compiler’s wisdom? Yes, you *could*, but then (e.g.) `for ((init; condition; step)); do ...; ((previous = current)); done` becomes (e.g.) `for ((init;;)); do ...; ((step)); ((condition)) || break; ((previous = current)); done`.

On one hand, a tiny bit of something (such as thin air) may have been “saved”. On the other hand, the code became assembler-like and harder to write, read and maintain.

To find a balance there^^^ and **{not,}** optimize when it **{doesn’t,does}** matter is a lifelong struggle. It may be something like CDO, which is like OCD, but sorted correctly.

```sh
fibonacci1() {
  local -ai fib=(0 1)
  local -i i
  for ((i = $1; i > 2; i -= 2)) {
    printf '%d %d ' "${fib[@]}"
    fib=($((fib[0] + fib[1])) $((fib[0] + 2 * fib[1])))
  }
  echo "${fib[@]::i}"
}

fibonacci2() {
  trap 'trap - return; echo' return
  local -i a=0 b=1 i="$1"
  ((i)) || return 0
  printf '%d' "$a"
  ((--i)) || return 0
  printf ' %d' "$b"
  for ((;;)); do
    ((--i)) || return 0
    printf ' %d' "$((a += b))"
    ((--i)) || return 0
    printf ' %d' "$((b += a))"
  done
}

for ((i = 0; i <= 30; ++i)); do
  for fibonacci in fibonacci{1,2}; do
    echo -n "${fibonacci}(${i}): "
    "$fibonacci" "$i"
  done
done
```